# Multi threading in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table where I have 1000+ rows. I need to write a springboot app that reads the table rows one by one and make a rest call to another service that accepts one JSON at a time. Looping through the table 1 by 1 does not seem to be an optimal solution. Can this be achieved by multi-threading, if so how can that be done ? Or do we have any better option for this, can someone help ?

Comment: Look into ThreadPoolExecutor. You could read all the records from the database and add each one as a job into a ThreadPoolExecutor which would use multiple threads to perform the REST calls.

Comment: Try to use Spring-Batch with Parallel Processing. Assuming your rows can be read independently.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html

Comment: Instead of reading one row or all at once reading in batch and then adding them to pool would be another good approach. In this case you wont get stuck due to network or huge data retrieval. Also keeping certain number of threads will give better perf too.

Answer (score 0):

At a time you can read suppose N records at a time from for example 50,you can use more than 1 thread to read records from database as  you are only reading and not writing, once you have read the record then you can create N number of Threads to call external service from ExecutorService, and Each Thread of Executor service can have data of 1 record which will call that external service

Comment: Can you please give me an example or a resource on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ‘@async’. Its one of the easiest ways of executing multiple threads in springboot

Comment: I am using JPA for accessing the DB. So , I will still have to get all the records using. findAll() and store them into list. And then for each element in the list I have to loop around and make the rest call using that element. I can use Async for making that call. Is it possible to get each element one by one asynchronously and make the rest call and then go for the next element in the db and do the same

Comment: Wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you have to read a DB table one row by another row? you can have just one sql statement and get all the rows that you need (achieved in your repository layer if it's a spring boot app) and then use multiple threading as described by other people (@Async, ExecutorService, etc...) in your service classes.